# Resolving EWS 'ErrorAccessDenied' error 'The requested web method is unavailable to this caller or application'

Tags: exchangewebservices

I'm creating a Microsoft Outlook Add-in using office.js and the Exchange Web Service. The add-in makes a few SOAP requests using Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(). During development of the add-in, the SOAP requests I've configured have worked fine. Now that a wider variety of users are using the add-in, we're seeing issues with some of the makeEwsRequestAsync calls. Notably, the error logs have been showing the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">a:ErrorAccessDenied</faultcode>
      <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The requested web method is unavailable to this caller or application.</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <e:ResponseCode xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">ErrorAccessDenied</e:ResponseCode>
        <e:Message xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">The requested web method is unavailable to this caller or application.</e:Message>
      </detail>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The requests that are returning this are:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" 
   xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
        <soap:Header>
                <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010" />
        </soap:Header>
        <soap:Body>
                <m:ResolveNames ReturnFullContactData="true" SearchScope="ContactsActiveDirectory">
                        <m:UnresolvedEntry>smtp</m:UnresolvedEntry>
                </m:ResolveNames>
        </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:GetUserAvailabilityRequest>
      <t:TimeZone xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
        <Bias>480</Bias>
        <StandardTime>
          <Bias>0</Bias>
          <Time>02:00:00</Time>
          <DayOrder>5</DayOrder>
          <Month>10</Month>
          <DayOfWeek>Sunday</DayOfWeek>
        </StandardTime>
        <DaylightTime>
          <Bias>-60</Bias>
          <Time>02:00:00</Time>
          <DayOrder>1</DayOrder>
          <Month>4</Month>
          <DayOfWeek>Sunday</DayOfWeek>
        </DaylightTime>
      </t:TimeZone>
      <m:MailboxDataArray>
        <t:MailboxData>
          <t:Email>
            <t:Address>user1234@example.com</t:Address>
          </t:Email>
          <t:AttendeeType>Required</t:AttendeeType>
          <t:ExcludeConflicts>false</t:ExcludeConflicts>
        </t:MailboxData>
      </m:MailboxDataArray>
      <t:FreeBusyViewOptions>
        <t:TimeWindow>
          <t:StartTime>2019-04-21T17:00:00</t:StartTime>
          <t:EndTime>2019-04-23T16:59:59</t:EndTime>
        </t:TimeWindow>
        <t:MergedFreeBusyIntervalInMinutes>30</t:MergedFreeBusyIntervalInMinutes>
        <t:RequestedView>FreeBusy</t:RequestedView>
      </t:FreeBusyViewOptions>
    </m:GetUserAvailabilityRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

When running these requests from my test accounts, they do not return the error response and are working fine. I suspect the users receiving this error are using a version of Outlook managed by their IT department and the errors are security related. I'm not familiar enough with how Outlook or the Exchange Servers are setup in relation to how that impacts the makeEwsRequestAsync() requests to search for a resolution to this.